# How to make UITableViewCells be selected by default for Editing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

[image]

In the screenshot above I have manually selected the cells by clicking them but I want all the cells to be selected for editing by default.

Comment: cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
use it or give your code...:)

Comment: try this cell.selected = YES; in cellForRowAtIndex: Method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code....

```
 for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
 {
     NSIndexPath *indexP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [tblView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexP animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [self tableView:tblView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexP];
 }
```

Where `tblView` is your `tableView`.