# Get the indexpath of the selected cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uialertview

When user taps on the default `delete` button in `UITableView` Edit mode,The user should get an alertview and if he hits Delete again in the AlertView the row should get deleted.Initially I have done this with the following code without the AlertView and it worked fine.

```
  [[self categoriesArray]removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   NSArray *indexPathsToRemove = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
   [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
   [self.categoriesArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath]  atomically:YES];
```

But now,as i have to use the same code in alertview delegate method.i dont know how to get the `[indexPath row]`

Comment: u want to delete data when u tapped on cell even tblView is not in edit mode :?

Comment: You can use loop for that - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758824/how-to-make-uitableviewcells-be-selected-by-default-for-editing/12758925#12758925 instead of select the cell you can remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your indexpath to the `UIAlertView` Tag and get from Delegate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath // indexPath is here
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
       UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Are you sure want to delete" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
       [alertView setTag:indexPath.row]; // Assigning here.
        [alertView show];
    }
}
    // UIAlertView Delegate

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%d",alertView.tag); // Your Indexpath is here

**Edited:**

    NSIndexPath * path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:alertView.tag inSection:0];
    [[self categoriesArray]removeObjectAtIndex:[path row]];
    NSArray * indexPathsToRemove = [NSArray arrayWithObject:path];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [self.categoriesArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath]  atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Try now with this.

Comment: set indexPath.row to Tag, indexPath.row is compatible with int.

Comment: Can u see my code? its not working in the second line as i have to use only indexpath and not indexpath.row

Answer (score 2):

Set the tag to alert view on commitEditingStyle method as

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath // indexPath is here
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Delete Record" message:@"Are you sure to delete the record." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
       alert.tag = indexPath.row;
       [alert show];
    }
}
```

On `Alert delegate` method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     if(buttonIndex == 1)//YES button clicked
     {
         [[self categoriesArray]removeObjectAtIndex:alertView.tag];
     }
}
```

Comment: @ChandraSekhar what u set indexpath.row or indexpath. Set indexPath.row.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` makes this information available to you via:

`- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow`

or if multiple selections are made:

`- (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedRows`

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSLog(@"%@",indexPath); is showing null

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method? Are you calling `deselectRowAtIndexPath` anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Use alert view inside this delegate method

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and then do whatever you want to do if the user clicks delete. if the user pressess delete in the alertview then you have to use alert view delegate method to handle it.